# Task queue for deferred tasks in GAE with python

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm sorry if this question has in fact been asked before. I've searched around quite a bit and found pieces of information here and there but nothing that completely helps me.

I am building an app on Google App engine in python, that lets a user upload a file, which is then being processed by a piece of python code, and then resulting processed file gets sent back to the user in an email.

At first I used a deferred task for this, which worked great. Over time I've come to realize that since the processing can take more than then 10 mins I have before I hit the DeadlineExceededError, I need to be more clever.

I therefore started to look into task queues, wanting to make a queue that processes the file in chunks, and then piece everything together at the end.

My present code for making the single deferred task look like this:

```
_=deferred.defer(transform_function,filename,from,to,email)
```

so that the transform_function code gets the values of filename, from, to and email and sets off to do the processing.

Could someone please enlighten me as to how I turn this into a linear chain of tasks that get acted on one after the other? I have read all documentation on Google app engine that I can think about, but they are unfortunately not written in enough detail in terms of actual pieces of code.

I see references to things like:

```
taskqueue.add(url='/worker', params={'key': key})
```

but since I don't have a url for my task, but rather a transform_function() implemented elsewhere, I don't see how this applies to me…

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can just keep calling deferred to run your task when you get to the end of each phase.
Other queues just allow you to control the scheduling and rate, but work the same.

I track the elapsed time in the task, and when I get near the end of the processing window the code stops what it is doing, and calls defer for the next task in the chain or continues where it left off, depending if its a discrete set up steps or a continues chunk of work. This was all written back when tasks could only run for 60 seconds.

However the problem you will face (it doesn't matter if it's a normal task queue or deferred) is that each stage could fail for some reason, and then be re-run so each phase must be idempotent.

For long running chained tasks, I construct an entity in the datastore that holds the description of the work to be done and tracks the processing state for the job and then you can just keep rerunning the same task until completion. On completion it marks the job as complete.

Comment: Thanks - conceptually I have no problem understanding what you mean, it's putting it into practice that it is the problem, I'm afraid. If I  put another call to a deferred task inside my already deferred task, will the first one still not eventually throw the deadlineExceededError? Or how do I "stop" the first task from running, with a return statement?

Comment: No you mis understand.  The very last thing you do is call deferred which schdules a new task. Then make sure you return Status 200 and that running task is complete.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the 10 minutes timeout you can direct the request to a backend or a B type module
using the "_target" param.

BTW, any reason you need to process the chunks sequentially? If all you need is some notification upon completion of all chunks (so you can "piece everything together at the end")
you can implement it in various ways (e.g. each deferred task for a chunk can decrease a shared datastore counter [read state, decrease and update all in the same transaction] that was initialized with the number of chunks. If the datastore update was successful and counter has reached zero you can proceed with combining all the pieces together.) An alternative for using deferred that would simplify the suggested workflow can be pipelines (https://code.google.com/p/appengine-pipeline/wiki/GettingStarted).